# Facebook social plugins integration url

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Hello i have this problem i want the url to only show the title

From this:

[image: From this]
To this:

[image: To this]

Hope you guys can help

Best regards
Mats Krüger

Answer (score 0):

You cannot facebook will read read the meta data and will automatically show description and image. You can disable only the image in the facebook window.